# Building a Building - Is the building clean?

Tags: game, design-patterns, kotlin, file-structure

I'm writing a small game and I use Kotlin for that. I want to model my buildings with the following class:

```java
class Building (
    val name: String,
    val inputs: Array<Resource>,
    val outputs: Array<Resource>
) {}
```

I want to create multiple instances of this class for the map but I don't want to fill the constructor parameters every time with the same data for the same building. So my idea was to make the constructor private and write creator functions in the companion object.

```java
class Building private constructor(
    val name: String,
    val inputs: Array<Resource>,
    val outputs: Array<Resource>
) {

    companion object {
        fun createWoodcutter(): Building = Building(
            "Woodcutter",
            arrayOf(
                Resource(ResourceType.WOOD, 1),
                Resource(ResourceType.WORKFORCE, 3),
                Resource(ResourceType.MONEY, 10)
            ),
            arrayOf(Resource(ResourceType.PLANKS, 1))
        )
    }
}
```

But I don't know if this strategy counts as clean code or is there a better way or design pattern for this?

Comment: For the record, when/if this game is available to play, I would love to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would recommend using a `data class`. In order to do this, it's better to use `List` rather than `Array` (because Array does not support hashCode/equals)

```
data class Building (
    val name: String,
    val inputs: List<Resource>,
    val outputs: List<Resource>
)
```

Actually, considering that the order of elements doesn't matter you could use `Set` or any iterable data structure as well, but my experience is that `List` is usually the fastest to iterate through.

As for using the companion object, that's entirely possible and will be similar to static factory methods, but I like to go beyond that and have a completely separate factory class for this. The reasoning being that I don't want to tightly couple my `Building` with the actual data, what if I would like to have two entirely different games in the future that both use the `Building` ? What if I would like to let the user design their own buildings? Either way, I see many reasons to use a separate factory class/object than use the companion object.

In Kotlin it is as easy as defining an `object BuildingFactory`.

```
object BuildingFactory {
    fun woodcutter(): Building = Building(
        "Woodcutter",
        listOf(
            Resource(ResourceType.WOOD, 1),
            Resource(ResourceType.WORKFORCE, 3),
            Resource(ResourceType.MONEY, 10)
        ),
        listOf(Resource(ResourceType.PLANKS, 1))
    )
}
```

Then you can create instances as easy as `BuildingFactory.woodcutter()`

Another approach could be to have a configuration data file specifying the buildings available and reading from that file. Then construct a building based on a name.

Answer (score 0):

As addition to @Simon Frosbergs answer, I would create an interface for the factory:

```
interface BuildingFactory{
    fun build(...) : Building
}
```

For the param you can choose for enums or Strings:

```
enum class BuildingType{
    Woodcutter
}
```

The enums are typesafe and the Strings are not.
The drawback for enums is that every time you add a BuildingType, you change the enum.
Therefor every module depending on that enum has to change as well.
(If you're not using multiple modules, this problem can be ignored)

Also, note that your companion object can implement an interface.
Therefor you can bind the static functions to one factory implementation:

```
object DefaultBuildingFactory : BuildingFactory{
    override fun build(type : BuildingType): Building = when(type){
        BuildingType.WoodCutter -> Building(
            "Woodcutter",
            listOf(
                Resource(ResourceType.WOOD, 1),
                Resource(ResourceType.WORKFORCE, 3),
                Resource(ResourceType.MONEY, 10)
            ),
            listOf(Resource(ResourceType.PLANKS, 1))
        )
    }
}

class Building private constructor(
    val name: String,
    val inputs: Array<Resource>,
    val outputs: Array<Resource>
) {
    companion object : BuildingFactory{
        override fun build(type : BuildingType) = DefaultBuildingFactory.build(type)
    }
}
```

Here you delegate the interface to DefaultBuildingFactory.
in kotlin [interface delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#overriding-a-member-of-an-interface-implemented-by-delegation) is build in:

```
class Building private constructor(
    val name: String,
    val inputs: Array<Resource>,
    val outputs: Array<Resource>
) {
    companion object : BuildingFactory by DefaultBuildingFactory
}
```